# Unable to import a npm module I downloaded

Tags: npm, import, npm-install, sveltekit, animate-on-scroll

I'm running a SvelteKit application with the Animate on Scroll (aos) module. This worked like a charm but due to the nature of my project, I needed to modify a few lines in the module, so I pulled the project from GitHub, modified it, rebuilt it and imported it via a local dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
    "aos": "file:/path/to/aos"
}
```

Whenever I try to import the module now however: `import AOS  from 'aos';`, I get this error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: The requested module '/@fs/C:/path/to/aos/dist/aos.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

**Note that** this also happens when I pull the repository and try to import it locally without changing it. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: I also tried to create a barebone SvelteKit app using `npm init svelte@next test-app` and install the package there - with the same result ...

Comment: I have now temporarily included the minified JS and CSS files as static imports on the page to at least get it to work, even if it's not pretty